# Deletion of reference underlying

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

What will happen to reference if underlying variable whom it was referring got deleted?

for e.g. why below code is giving 12 as output i checked both on gcc and msvc

```
int *x = new int(1);
int& y = *x;
delete x;
x=NULL;
int z = 12;
y=z;
cout<<"Y = "<<y<<endl;
```

Comment: The behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing an object whose memory has been deleted is undefined behaviour, regardless of whether you do it directly or through a reference.

The fact that the code outputs `12` on GCC and MSVC is largely irrelevant: it could output `13`, or `42`, or `potato` and still be standard-conformant.

Comment: When I woke up this morning, `potato` was written on my bathroom mirror in blood. I was terrified until I saw this Q&A. Now I know that it was just a result of Kapil's time-travelling UB! Phew!

Comment: The potato made my day :D

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing memory after having released it. That's undefined. "Undefined" does not mean that the program crashes, or even that different things will happen in different runs. It merely means that anything might happen.

Sadly, when you access memory that has just been released, *usually* nothing bad will happen. This is precisely the behavior that you are seeing. I suspect that trying the same in MSVC in debug mode will, in fact, give you a different result, as it has some modes in which it destroys the content of dynamic memory as soon as it's released.

On Linux, try valgrind (look it up) or the address sanitizer (compile with -sanitize=address). Both catch this sort of errors.